# Worklight XSL transformation after getting response

Tags: xslt, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am novice to Worklight. I was trying XSL transformation using:

> transformation : {            type : "xslFile",           xslFile : "filtered.xsl",
>         }

But for some reason if adapter fails to get response(status code != 200). Then it dumps the whole XSL in "errors".
So is it possible to do transformation of the response only if status code  == 200?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this issue
1) in the adapter JavaScript you can check the returned status code

```
function getStoriesFiltered() {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : 'rss/edition.rss',
        transformation : {
            type : 'xslFile',
            xslFile : 'filtered.xsl'
        }
    };
    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    if (response.statusCode !==  200) {
        return {'statusCode' : 'something went wrong'};
    }
    return response;
}
```

Or you can check it in the adapter xsl with a `<xsl:if>` element depending on what is returned from your backend.

Comment: I was able to do with the first approach but in the other approach 
<xsl:if test="statusCode = 200">
</xsl:if>
doesn't works.
Coz when I print <xsl:value-of select="statusCode" />
it gives blank not 200